# Is there a way to check if the underlying file for a file descriptor has been unlinked?

Tags: c, macos, filesystems, file-descriptor

(I know FSEvents exists, I can't use it in this scenario since I am trying to operate on polling as opposed to an event loop which requires a secondary thread)

I am writing a file watcher interface and am working on the macOS side of things. I have a file descriptor and I am trying to check whether the underlying file has been unlinked. I would rather not have to carry around the path to use for `access` calls and macOS lacks a procfs so I can't get a pathname from the fd.

Is there a way to check whether the underlying file an fd refers to has been unlinked under these constraints or do I need to bring at least the path? Does `fstat` have a field that can achieve this that I don't realise?

Comment: `st_nlink` in `fstat`? If this goes to zero, then the last name for that file has been unlinked. For files with multiple hard links are you interested in *the name* that you used to open that file being gone (st_nlink won't help much) or is it enough to know that the last name is gone?

Comment: @dratenik Is `nlink` hitting 0 the as inotify reporting `IN_DELETE_SELF`?

Comment: As far as I can tell if you have the file open, IN_DELETE_SELF [will not trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890116/inotify-does-not-raise-delete-self-if-an-open-file-fd-exists) until the last process closes it. For files that are not open, those should align, yes.

Comment: @dratenik Okay so I should wait until actual deletion to line up with the same conditions as inotify - thanks!